# Javascript - Add marker when an australian state is clicked on the map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, leaflet

Currently I am using choropleth map and I am able to click each state in Australian map. However I wanted to add a marker when I click on a state. So by the time I clicked on a state, markers would show.

```
function zoomToFeature(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature
    })        
}

geojson = L.geoJson(australiastates, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);

var systemIcon = L.icon ({
    iconUrl: 'system.png',
    iconSize:  [40, 80]
})

L.marker([-37.81,144.9631], {icon: systemIcon}).addTo(map);
```

That is the click listeners. However I am not sure where the code below would be placed to add the marker when I click the state

```
var systemIcon = L.icon ({
    iconUrl: 'system.png',
    iconSize:  [40, 80]
})

L.marker([-37.81,144.9631], {icon: systemIcon}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: You seem to be adding a click listener and you want the code to execute when clicked, so… perhaps add it to the function assigned to the listener (i.e. *zoomToFeature*) or add a second listener?

Comment: Looks like you are using leaflet, you might want to add that tag.

Comment: Where is the marker supposed to go?The centroid of the state? or the arbitrary `[-37.81,144.9631]` you reference?